# How to pass CLI arguments to my Pulumi code?

Tags: pulumi

For instance, can I write something like `pulumi up -ec2_count=15` so that `ec2_count` is my custom arg I interpret in my Pulumi code?

I couldn't find such capability [in their docs](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/cli/pulumi_up/), but it's strange that it's not possible...

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. I don't know if its even a good practice, but I need to somehow dynamically pass the image version from the previous build into Pulumi, to deploy the correct container. Have you solved it already?

Answer (score 3):

You can **dynamically** pass config entries to to `pulumi up` by using the `-c` flag:

> pulumi up -c APPLICATION_DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION=latest

and require it in your code

```
   Pulumi.run(ctx -> {
      var config = ctx.config();
      var version = config.require("APPLICATION_DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION");
      .       
      .
      .
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that it could be possible, but maybe is not the best approach to use Pulumi.

You can get this from environment variables or config set with Pulumi cli.

Ex:

Env Vars:

os.Getenv("ec2_count")

Config:

pulumi config set dev:myvars:ec2_count: 1

config.require("ec2_count")

https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/config/

Comment: Yes, that's indeed an option, but I'm looking for a way to pass args straight to the `pulumi up` command